# loading all the import maps from a separate JSON file in Single-SPA?

Tags: ejs, single-spa, single-spa-angular

i am working on a micro-front end application with the help of Single-SPA framework.
i am able to import and make it work by adding the MFE routes directly in index.ejs file.

since we have a lot of MFEs, i don't want to keep them all in index.ejs.

want to keep all the routes in separate JSON file and import then JSON file in to index.ejs file.

so the question is , is there a way we can import JSON file directly in EJS template ??

there are similar questions in stackover flow but all of the answers are pointing to `render` method which i don't find it on single-spa library ?

Answer (score 1):

**step-1 :** create a JSON file under src folder (ex: src/local-map.json)

**step-2 :** remove the JSON map from index.ejs and paste in the created JSON in step-1

**step-3:** update the index.ejs like below

```
<% if (isLocal) { %>
    <script type="systemjs-importmap" src="./local-map.json"></script>
  <% } %>
```

**step-4:** add the below code in webpack.config.js or webpack-proxy.config.js

```
 devServer: {
      static:'src'
    }
```

that's it :)

Comment: Do you know a setup that allows my production endpoints to be on a static file too?

Comment: Hi @sravan I tried your solution but this is not working when refreshing the page inside a nested route created by the MFE application. The index try to point to localhost/9000/<path> instead of current ./src. Do you know something that could avoid that?